# How to create a VPN Connection to Office Server

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-access

I have been having this problem for the past 3 weeks and its really killing me. I am trying to create a VPN connection to my Win2k8R2 Server which is a Virtual Server.  The server has a IP Address 192.168.1.4. I have made port forward for Ports 1723/1701 & 47 (PPTP/L2TP etc) on the router. Have disabled Windows firewall on the Server, which has RRAS Server installed (192.168.1.4) Client/Server security is identical.

But when I try to connect I get error 800. I have put the server into the DMZ Zone as well. Would anyone know how I can go about solving this issue?

Comment: Is the server connected to the internet/network? Can you ping it?

Comment: You have PPTP VPN? Did you unblock port number 47 or IP Protocol 47? Try this document http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd8bd57f-c730-4387-be4c-e5978185027e.aspx, but first see what's your VPN type.

Comment: You do understand that `192.168.1.4` is not valid outside of the office lan right?

Comment: Hi All, first of all thank you so very much for all the replies...

Comment: Hi All, first of all thank you so very much for all the replies. @Matthew, Yes the Server is connected to the server. & I can ping the server within the local network.  Ashtray, I have configured the VPN on PPTP protocol & have already enabled port TCP1723/UDP1701/UDP GRE 47 & thanks for the Document. ramhound, that was one of my concerns. I was dialing my private address but later I dialied my external IP as well then I get error 806. GRE protocol is blocked. I requested my ISP provider to unblock the port but the External IP I have is dynamic so do not know how that will work out!!

Comment: @RochelleNNilangaChandraseke | A dynamic IP might make it difficult for you. I assume you have configured a static IP on your server. Check your router firewalls and see if that is blocking it. At this point we can only assume you have correctly configured the VPN systems on your server.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams, My Server on my Internal Network has a Static IP. but what I learnt from our ISP is that the External IP they have given is a Dynamic one and they are "not sure" is the ports are been blocked.... so I guess I have hit a dead end ey?

Comment: @RochelleNNilangaChandraseke | As you can imagine there isn't a lot you or we can do about it if the ISP is blocking something. Might want to ask them till you get an answer. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You may get this error if the subnet is the same on both ends.

I.E both local network (that you are connecting from) and remote network (that you are trying to connect to via VPN) has the same subnet like: 192.168.1.xxx

Therefore, it is a good idea NOT to use 192.168.1.xxx on your business network which you will be VPNing to.

If the problem persists follow this :

1) Ping the VPN server to ensure it is available.

2) Confirm your computer's/Router's firewall settings are still configured to permit traffic to and from your VPN. If you are using PPTP protocol, TCP Port 1723 and GRE Protocol 47 must be opened/enabled and for L2TP ensure UDP port 1701 is not blocked.

3) Confirm that the firewall settings will allow traffic on UDP ports 500 and 4500 if using IKEv2 for the VPN tunnel.

Hope it could help.

Comment: hi rose, thank you for your answer.  my office network is unfortunately on 192.168.2.xxx but I have configured the VPN client to get IP in the range of 10.0.0.xxx. Also the router I have has VPN Pass through enabled and above ports been forwarded.  But the problem is that when i do a port check for my external IP the port 47 and 1701 is closed only 1723 is open.... I already informed my ISP to open the relevant ports so lets see ho that goes ey? cheers